# Looped commands in R

Tags: r, regression

I have multiple data tables that im trying to run the same command for, and sicne i dont want to type each one for every command, I'm trying to loop it. They have the same variables.

say they are named
data_2018q1
data_2018q2
data_2019q1
data_2019q2
i want to run

`lm(VD4020~V2010+V2007, data = )`for all of them, without having to run multiple lm()but no idea how to.
for reproducible example, use cars:
`cars1 = cars cars2 = cars*2 cars3 = cars*3 lm(speed~dist, data= )`

for the three of them.
Thanks ahead!

Comment: First step: Put your datasets in a list. Second step: `lapply(yourlist, function(DF) lm(y ~ x, data = DF))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put them into a list and use lapply.

```
cars1 <- cars
cars2 <- cars*2
cars3 <- cars*3
cars_list <- list(cars1, cars2, cars3)
lapply(cars_list, function(x) lm(speed~dist, data = x))
```